# Service to Service authentication , service identity and access rights management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, rest, soa

I am currently developing a distributed application using Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Sinatra and pure Rack web services.

I will have few services (RESTful , not SOAP based) which will communicate using JSON and I would need a way to secure and verify the identity of each of those services during the communication between them, so no one could pretend to be a service and make requests to the other services.

The core idea is to treat other services as "users" and be able to verify their identity and limit their access to data if necessary.

**So the question is how to do this using only Ruby and how to manage effectively the service identities and their access rights.**

**Should I build some additional authentication service usable by the services ?**

**Should I build internal gems to provide some connection middleware with keys/shared secrets ?**

Is there maybe some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would generate an application id and secret that you could pass with each request. Since you are not dealing with other users and just applications try looking into authentication tokens with devise.

Comment: This solution would work in the service relation "one to many", but this is more of a "many to many" relationship here. Each service should be able to talk to another if necessary. And if one of the services would get compromised, I should be able to isolate it from the rest of the group by revoking the access rights to others or revoking the access key.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe some sort of central authentication server that you can use to manage service credentials for applications? Its not my area of expertise but I think this would be the best way

Comment: I am thinking about something in between, like a local copies of valid credentials which will be updated by authentication service which will be able to deploy them automatically through gems. Something along those lines. If someone would have a better solution, even in few months, please leave a comment here :)

Comment: if you can easily deploy to both services holding an appkey/secret in the code is the simplest thing that can work. In the case of a security breach, regenerate the keys, change both services and redeploy. If deploying is hard, put the keys in config.

Answer (score 0):

I think OAuth is a protocol that is commonly used for web service - to - web service runtime authentication, especially with RESTful APIs.